# Get all pictures in SD and storing it in Array

Tags: android, arraylist, android-resources

I'm storing the icons in an ArrayList with resid (these images are stored in the drawable folder). I want to store the images from gallery items and providing the resid. How can I do that?

```
 List<StickerView> mStickers = new ArrayList<>();

 int[] mResIds = new int[]{R.mipmap.st1, R.mipmap.st2, R.mipmap.st5};
```

I want to store the gallery images in below array how can do that?

```
 int[] imageIds=new int[]{};
```

Comment: Please elaborate and make your question more easy to understand.

Comment: Gallery items are not app resources. So, they don't have any id. You can only reference them by path.

Comment: there is no resID for non-resource files

Answer (score 1):

you can`t put it in array of int cause  pictures in gallery has no ID

instead you can Do it ,  this code to get all files in specific Directory

```
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] listFile;



 public void getFromSdcard()
    {
        File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"YOUR_Directory");

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, listFile[0].getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {

                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT Access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

hope it`s Help